# linux palindrom string arguments

Tags: c, palindrome

I have to write a program which receives words as arguments.For every argument I have to create a thread that verify if the word is palindrom and in that case it will increment a global variable sum.
This is what I did

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#define MAX 15

pthread_mutex_t mtx;
int sum=0;
void *Pal(void *arg) {
 char *p=char arg;
// char p=*(int*)arg;
int len,j;
int flag=0;
printf("%s received. ", p);
len= strlen(p);
for (j=0; j<len; j++) {
  pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
  if(p[j] ==p[len-j-1])
  flag +=1;
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx); 
}
if (flag==len) {
 printf("%s is palindrome.good job \n", p);
 sum +=1; 
}
 else {
 printf("%s is not palindrome.Fail \n", p);
 }
 }  

int main( int argc, char* argv[]) {
int i;
pthread_mutex_init(&mtx, NULL);
pthread_t t[MAX]; 
for(i=1 ; i<argc; i++) 
  pthread_create(&t[i], NULL, Pal, argv[i]);
for(i=1 ; i<argc; i++)
  pthread_join(t[i], NULL);
printf("The global sum is:%d \n", sum);
return 0;
}
```

The problem is there: char p=char arg.I don't know how to make the relation between the strings and the arguments.
If someone can help me I would be apreciated.

Comment: Actually here, my mistake: char *p=char arg;

Comment: The line `char *p = char arg;` doesn't make any sense, starting with the fact that `char * != char`.

Comment: Yes, the problem was that I didn't know how to write that line with char, to make the connection with the arguments.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the cast because `void *` is converted to any poitner type without a cast in c, so

```
char *p = arg;
```

would work.

I didn't check the rest of the program, so I can't say if the program will work as you expect, but at least this fixes one problem.

Comment: it wooorks. thank you so much.this is the answer I was expecting for.I didn't know how to write that line with char.Thank you again!!

Comment: @Boolean: .. which has been pointed out before. Please read the [tour], it's not too late for that.